# How to upload an Image to Facebook album using Facebook sdk 4 Android Studio

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, post, android-studio

Hi everyone I have a question.Please help me so first of all here is my code :

```
 Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();
    final String imagepath = getpath(chosenImageUri);
    final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);


ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    GraphRequest request =   new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    getIntent().getStringExtra("albumid") + "/photos",
    null, 
    HttpMethod.POST, 
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
       public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                }
            });
    Bundle parametre = new Bundle();
    parametre.putByteArray("source", byteArray);
    request.setParameters(parametre);

    request.executeAsync();
```

I wanna post an image to Facebook album who I am get the picture and set into GridView. I don't know what can I do anymore. I spend 1.5 days for this upload process. I need help.

I have this error :

```
{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[user_likes, user_posts, user_friends, user_photos, user_location, public_profile, user_birthday]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone I found the solution.This is for when you want upload to album which you are pick. So I wanna explain:
First of all you make this:

```
      private CallbackManager callbackManager;
         LoginManager manager;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gridview);

            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
....
}
```

Then choose from Gallery or Camera an upload it.

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_grid, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_upload:
                chooseImageDialog("", this, false);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    public void chooseImageDialog(final String title,
                                  final Context context, final boolean redirectToPreviousScreen) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery \n",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, RQ_GALLERY);
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intentfile = new Intent(
                                "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                        startActivityForResult(intentfile, RQ_CAMERA);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case RQ_GALLERY:
                List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
                manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
                manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
                manager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Upload(data);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

                    }
                });
                break;
            case RQ_CAMERA:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
                    manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
                    manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissions);
                    manager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                            Upload(data);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

                        }
                    });
                } else {
               /*     Toast.makeText(activityname.this, "Unable to get Image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }
                break;
        }


    }


    private void Upload(Intent data) {
        if(data != null){
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(accessToken, getIntent().getStringExtra("albumid") + "/photos", null,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        }
                    });

            Bundle params = request.getParameters();
            Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();
            final String imagepath = GetPath(chosenImageUri);
            final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            params.putByteArray("source", byteArray);
            request.setParameters(params);
            request.executeAsync();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Image was selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private String GetPath(Uri chosenImageUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(chosenImageUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            ;
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;
    }
```

If you can improve this solution ,please post it.Thank you .